# How to connect to local network throgh WiFi AP and connect to internet through 3G at the same time?

Tags: android, time, wifi, 3g

I want my smart phone can get sensor data from one embedded device through one WiFi AP, then push the data to internet through 3G. The architecture is like below list.

embedded device <- UART -> WiFi AP with UART <- WiFi and TCP/IP -> My Smart Phone <-> 3G's TCP/IP -> Web server's DB

I search some key words (wifi 3g same time) on this site and google, but the available answers are needed to be rooted.

I want to find the solution which can run on normal smart phone. If you have any idea, please give me some hints or answers.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That should be possible using [WiFi Direct](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html). You could have one ad-hoc WiFi connection to your embedded device while being connected to the internet via 3G, or have one ad-hoc WiFi connection to the embedded device and one infrastructure WiFi connection to the internet. Though I haven't tested this myself.

Comment: I use WiFi AP which has uart interface to connect to my embedded device. This WiFi AP doesn't support WiFi Direct. Thanks for your reply!